# Detecting type of repository from URL

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

Is there any way to detect programatically (maybe, by sending some request to server) what the type of repository is (e.g. Git, SVN, Mercurial)?

I've already thought about parsing URL, but it seems impossible. For example:

- Mercurial repo: bitbucket.org/bos/hg-tutorial-hello
- SVN: vegastrike.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/vegastrike/trunk

Comment: Can you give an example where the information you seek is not in the URL?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart , of course. Mercurial repo: https://bitbucket.org/bos/hg-tutorial-hello. SVN: https://vegastrike.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/vegastrike/trunk. It's some example-links, that I've found in net. I've already thought about parsing the links, but it seems impossible.

Comment: I would add those examples to your question itself (instead of in a comment).

Comment: I think you're going to have to try each protocol until one works. I can't think of any generic way to request this information from the server.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart , can you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: Try to `git clone` it, and if that fails, try to `hg clone` it, and if that fails, try to `svn checkout` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way of doing this definitively. You can use some heuristics to determine which one it might be:

- If it contains 'svn', 'subversion' or 'svnroot' or 'trunk' in the URL, it's probably a SVN repository
- If it contains 'git', 'master' or '.git' in the URL, it's probably a Git repository
- If it contains 'hg' or 'mercurial' in the URL, it's probably a Mercurial repository
- If it contains 'cvs', 'CVSROOT' or 'HEAD' in the URL it's probably a CVS repository.

However you won't really know which one of these things it is until you try and clone it. There are HEAD operations you can do (if it's an http/s site) but this may not necessarily work - and in any case, you're going to have failed access logs if you try this anyway.

Note that some servers - like GitHub and BitBucket - will allow you to clone by more than one mechanism (e.g. checkout a Git repository as either a Git repo or an SVN repo).

Comment: But what about [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)? It does check of repository type by URL in clone-dialog window.

Comment: If given an HTTP or SSH repository, it almost certainly tries Git as the first attempt, and if that is missing either Git support or Git files then it will fallback to Mercurial - unless one of the other hints above give it an idea of what to check out.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to detect only these 3 types of repos:

- `git ls-remote $URL` returns true if $url points to a Git repo
- `hg id $URL` returns id for tip if $url points to a Mercurual repo or error-code 255 if not